# spring mockMVC testing method GET

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockmvc

i created post method in mockMVC (in spring boot project)
This is my method testing

This is my method testing

```
@Test
public void createAccount() throws Exception {
     AccountDTO accountDTO = new AccountDTO("SAVINGS", "SAVINGS");
     when(addaccountService.findByName("SAVING")).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
     when(addaccountService.createAccount(any())).thenReturn(createdAccountDTO);
    CreatedAccountDTO createdAccountDTO = new CreatedAccountDTO("a@wp.pl", "SAVINGS", "1234rds", uuid);

    mockMvc.perform(
             post("/account").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .content(asJsonString(AccountNewDTO)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(header().string("location", containsString("/account/"+uuid.toString())));
    System.out.println("aaa");
}
```

I want to write GET method.

how to write a get method in mock mvc? how to verify whether what I threw was returned?

Answer (score 5):

```
You can try the below for Mockmvc perform get and post methods
For get method

@Autowired
private MuffinRepository muffinRepository;

@Test
public void testgetMethod throws Exception(){
    Muffin muffin = new Muffin("Butterscotch");
    muffin.setId(1L);
    
    BddMockito.given(muffinRepository.findOne(1L)).
        willReturn(muffin);
        
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
        get("/muffins/1")).
        andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).
        andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("{\"id\":1, \"flavor\":\"Butterscotch\"}"));   
}

//Test to do post operation
@Test
public void testgetMethod throws Exception(){
    Muffin muffin = new Muffin("Butterscotch");
    muffin.setId(1L);
    
    BddMockito.given(muffinRepository.findOne(1L)).
        willReturn(muffin);
        
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
        post("/muffins")
        .content(convertObjectToJsonString(muffin))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().json(convertObjectToJsonString(muffin)));    
}

If the response is empty then make sure to override equals() and hashCode() method on the Entity your repository is working with

//Converts Object to Json String
private String convertObjectToJsonString(Muffin muffin) throws JsonProcessingException{
    ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectWriter().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    return writer.writeValueAsString(muffin);
}
```

Comment: @martine you can try the above code snippet to make mockmvc get and post operation

Answer (score 3):

You can use the static `get` method of the class `MockMvcRequestBuilders`, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

Example:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/account")).andExpect(...);
```

If you throw an exception within your controller method it will typically trigger execution of an exception handler which transforms the exception into a HTTP error response. By default, you could check if the status of the response was 500. If you have implemented your own exception handler you may want to check the response body as well to verify if it contains the expected error data.

Comment: thank you, so my get test method is:
       @Test
        public void getAccount()throws Exception {
     AccountDTO accountDTO = new AccountDTO();
     AccountDTO.setEmail("a@wp.pl");
        AccountDTO.setName("SAVINGS");         when(addaccountService.findByName("SAVING")).thenReturn(Optional.empty());      when(addaccountService.createAccount(any())).thenReturn(createdAccountDTO);

Comment: CreatedAccountDTO createdAccountDTO = new CreatedAccountDTO("a@wp.pl", "SAVINGS", "1234rds", uuid);
            mockMvc.perform(get("/account").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
        .content(asJsonString(accountDTO))).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(header().string("location", containsString("/users/"+uuid.toString())));;
        }

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :500
 <Click to see difference>


 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:55)
 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:82)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:617)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:179)

Comment: and I actually have a mistake.

what's wrong with my test? how to improve it?

Comment: @Test
    public void getUser()throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform( get( "/users" ) ).andExpect( status().isOk() ).andExpect( view().name( "home" ) );

Comment: It seems that the controller handling the GET request to the "/account" threw an exception. That is why you get status 500 instead of expected 200. Can you provide the code of your controller class which implements the GET method of "/account" (edit your original question)?